# Convert excel 2D array integer data into systemverilog 2D array

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I have an excel sheet which has 512 integers in array format 32(rows)x16(columns). I want to read these values into a verilog/SystemVerilog 2D integer array. What is the best way to perform this task. I was thinking of copy paste these values in text file in single column and then read one by one but not sure if that's the efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the spreadsheet to CSV text file using spaces as separators.

If you can convert the table to hexadecimal values, then `$readmemh` can do this directly. (convert to hex using `=DEC2HEX()` in Excel, or some other script).

Otherwise you can use `$fscanf`

```
foreach(integer_array[i,j]) 
  if(1==$fscanf(fd,"%d",integer_array[i][j]))
    continue;
  else
    $fatal(1, "not enough data to fill the array");
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, this worked like a charm. Only change I had to do is inside if statement:    if(1==$fscanf(fd,"%d",b1map[i][j]))   Maybe because I declared array as "int b1map[32][16]?